# How to add a cron job in my functions.php

Tags: functions, cron

My host is WPengine, I can't configure my crontab directly on the server so I need to do it on my side. Then I need to add a function to my functions.php right?

What is the function to be sure that this command is triggered every minute?

```
/usr/local/bin/curl --silent http://www.your-domain.com/?amina-cron=check >/dev/null 2>&1
```

TIA

Comment: WP cron does not work like that.  You can schedule a task for every minute but unless the application (WordPress) is running, it cannot fire a cron task every minute.  WordPress is only running when serving content.  https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_cron

Comment: @jdm2112 that's true. Or you can use external server which access WP site every minutes to fire the WP Cron event.